# PHP : Concatenate arrays with condition

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to read a session variable, create arrays and concatenate them :

**Session variable sample:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [idArticle] => 224
        [ntypeArticle] => 1
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [idArticle] => 556
        [ntypeArticle] => 2
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [idArticle] => 312
        [ntypeArticle] => 1
    )   
)
```

I need to read this arrays one by one and create arrays by "`ntypeArticle`".

If `ntypeArticle=1`, `create array1`

If `ntypeArticle=2`, `create array2`

**My code :**

```
$type1 = array();
$type2= array();
$typeAll = array();
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item)
{

    if ($item['ntypeArticle'] == 1) {
        $type1= array ( "Type" => '1', );
    } else {
        $type2= array ( "Type" => '2', );
    }
    array_push($typeAll , $type1 , $type2);
}
```

But this creates empty arrays.

**Wanted output :**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [type] => 1
)
[1] => Array
(
    [type] => 2
)
[2] => Array
(
    [type] => 1
)
)
```

Comment: you don't seem to be doing anything with the `$type1` or `$type2` after you have assigned values / arrays to them, where are the `$listArticleResult, $listArticlePax, $listArticlePlusieursPax` coming from?

Comment: Are `$listArticleResult`, `$listArticlePax`, `$listArticlePlusieursPax` ever defined somewhere?

Comment: `$type1= array ( "Type" => '1', );` will create a scalar variable called `$type1` but only contain the last entry in the loop `$type1[] = array ( "Type" => '1', );` will create an array of type1's

Comment: ___Just a note:___ The new array you say you want does not actually achieve anything over and above the original array. And exactly the same information could be got from the original array in its current form. Are you sure this is actually achieving anything

Comment: Well, of course it'll create empty values, you are inserting both `$type1` and `$type2` every time you loop, but only one variable is set with each loop, meaning that until both `$type1` and `$type2` has been given a value in the if clause, you'll continue to get empty values in your `$typeAll` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$newOp1 = array()
$newOp2 = array()
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item){
    if($item["ntypeArticle"] == 1){
       $newOp1[]['type'] = $item["ntypeArticle"]
    }else{
       $newOp2[]['type'] = $item["ntypeArticle"]
    }
}
print_r($newOp1);
print_r($newOp2);
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is this simple thing:

```
$out = [];
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $item)
{
    $out[$k] = ['Type' => $item['ntypeArticle']];
}
```

Now if you output `$out` variable you get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on information you provided, all you want to do is to extract `nTypeArticle` as `type` element. That's all.

```
//array from your example
$inputArray = array(
    array(
        'idArticle' => 224,
        'nTypeArticle' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'idArticle' => 556,
        'nTypeArticle' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'idArticle' => 312,
        'nTypeArticle' => 1
    ),
);

$outputArray = array_map(function($inputElement) {
    return array('type' => $inputElement['nTypeArticle']);
}, $inputArray);

var_dump($outputArray);
//Output (the same as yours):
//array (size=3)
//  0 => 
//    array (size=1)
//      'type' => int 1
//  1 => 
//    array (size=1)
//      'type' => int 2
//  2 => 
//    array (size=1)
//      'type' => int 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = new array();
$input = array(
array(
    "idArticle" => 224,
    "nTypeArticle" => 1
    ),
    array(
        "idArticle" => 556,
        "nTypeArticle" => 2
    ),
    array(
        "idArticle" => 312,
        "nTypeArticle" => 1
    )
);

foreach($input as $article) {
    array_push($output, new array("type"=>$article["nTypeArticle"]));
}
print_r($output);
```

This gives you the thing you asked for.
(Code has been not tested)